# Parsing objects to partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

How do I send an object to a partial view?

I have something like this:

---

View:

```
@{
    SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
}
<div>
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Partial/_PartialPage.cshtml")
</div>
```

How whould I manage to send the object `obj` to `_PartialPage`. And how would `_PartialPage` look like for me to handle that object?

Answer (score 2):

There is an overload ([`Html.Partial(HtmlHelper, String, Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402926%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)) which allows you to pass a model. So, in practice:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Partial/_PartialPage.cshtml", obj);
```

Then the partial would access `SomeObject`:

```
@model SomeObject

@* ... rest of view ... *@
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass any model to a strongly typed Partial View. There's an overload for Html.Partial method that accepts as paramether the model that you want to pass:

[Render Method MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402926%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
public static MvcHtmlString Partial(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string partialViewName,
    Object model
)
```

Make the Partial View strongly typed:

```
@model MyModel
```

Rendering the view:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Partial/_PartialPage.cshtml", myModel)
```